# Wordpress - different icon image depends of comment number

Tags: images, comments

I would like to add different icon depends of comments number. For example post has 10 comments and it has standard icon. When post has more than 10 comments (it's hot topic) it has different icon. Any clue how to do that?

Edit:

I created div with custom icon picture (png) next to the comments number. As I said I would like to find a way to change that picture (by php function I guess) when the number of comments will be more than 20 for example.

Comment: Hi Radosław Jakubiak, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ready function for doing such action:

Take a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_comments

This should really sole your problem as you can use an if statement deciding the picture, just remember you have to use the post_id in order to get the count.

Thank you!